# Do we need to follow http accept header on an error?

Tags: http-headers, http-error, media-type

Does HTTP require that the server return one of the accept header media types on an error? For instance we perform a POST with the accept header **application/vnd.foo.bar-v1+json**

and error occurs and the result is a **422**. Do we need to return the **application/vnd.foo.bar-v1+json** or can we return a different media type since an error occured? Could I return a **application/vnd.foo.errors-v1+json**?

Looking a W3 http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html I did not see an outright explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5:

> the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation

What this means is that the *body* of the response should contain the error, and the `Content-Type` identifies its type. For example, by default Tomcat returns an HTML page, so the `Content-Type` is set appropriately (to `text/html`, I believe).

If your error has the media type `application/vnd.foo.bar-v1+json` then you *should* set it as the `Content-Type`.